# Electron TrayIcon not working properly on linux

Tags: javascript, linux, electron, system-tray, trayicon

I'm trying to make an Electron app that runs on system tray, once the tray icon is clicked, the app window will appears.

I tested it on linux, windows and mac, on windows and mac it works perfectly, when I click the tray icon, the app window appears but on linux, when I click the tray icon a context menu appears (even tough i haven't set it) with the app name and the app window only appears if I click on the app name.

That's how I made the tray

```
let mainWindow
let tray = null;

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 400,
    height: 500,
    skipTaskbar: true,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  mainWindow.setMenu(null)

  mainWindow.hide();

  tray = new Tray("./assets/icon@2x.png");

  tray.on('click', () => {
    mainWindow.isVisible() ? mainWindow.hide() : mainWindow.show()
  })
  mainWindow.on('show', () => {
    tray.setHighlightMode('always')

    const pos = tray.getBounds()

    mainWindow.setPosition(pos.x - 195, pos.y + 30);
  })
  mainWindow.on('hide', () => {
    tray.setHighlightMode('never')
  })

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}
```

I want it to works how it works on windows and mac, when I click the tray icon, the app window appears, someone knows how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change your tray method from

```
tray.setHighlightMode()
```

to

```
tray.setToolTip()
```

this my code to prevent close win

```
            win.on('show', () => {
                //tray.setHighlightMode('always');
                tray.setToolTip("Server Started");


            });
            win.on('hide', () => {
                //tray.popUpContextMenu();
                tray.setToolTip("Server Started");
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an open issue with the electron project, there is nothing wrong with your code.

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/14941